# Perl script to search a word inside the directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

I'am looking for a perl script to grep for a string in all files inside a directory .

bash command .
Code:
`grep -r 'word' /path/to/dir`

Comment: What's wrong with that `grep` command?  And, as for "_looking for a perl script_", how far did you get in writing it?  Any particular problems?

Comment: I have to take user input from html form and search that word in the directory so cant use grep.@zdim

Comment: For recursive search (the `-r` in your `grep` command) use `File::Find` or `File::Find::Rule` to iterate over all files recursively, and then open each file and search line by line for the phrase.  Or, all of this can be done with `Path::Tiny` as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a fairly canonical task while I couldn't find straight answers with a possibly easiest and simples tool for the job, the handy [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump;  # dd
use Path::Tiny;  # path 

my $dir = shift // '.';

my $pattern = qr/word/;

my $ret = path($dir)->visit( 
    sub { 
        my ($entry, $state) = @_; 
        return if not -f; 
     
        for ($entry->lines) {
            if (/$pattern/) {
                print "$entry: $_";
                push @{$state->{$entry}}, $_;  
            }   
        }   
    },  
    { recurse => 1 } 
); 

dd $ret;  # print the returned complex data structure
```

The way a file is read here, using `lines`, is just one way to do that. It may not be suitable for extremely large files as it reads all lines at once, where one better read line by line.

The `visit` method is based on `iterator`, which accomplishes this task cleanly as well

```
my $iter = path($dir)->iterator({ recurse => 1 });

my $info;

while (my $e = $iter->()) { 
    next if not -f $e; 
    
    # process the file $e as needed
    #/$pattern/ and push @{$info->{$e}}, $_ and print "$e: $_" 
    #    for $e->lines 
}
```

Here we have to provide a data structure to accumulate information but we get more flexibility.

The [-f filetest](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X) used above, of a "plain" file, is still somewhat permissive; it allows for swap files, for example, which some editors keep during a session (vim for instance). Those will result in all kinds of matches. To stay with purely ASCII or UTF-8 files use `-T` test.

---

Otherwise, there are libraries for recursive traversal and searching, for example [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) (or [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule)) or [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule).

For completeness, here is a take with the core [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use File::Find;

my @dirs = @ARGV ? @ARGV : '.';

my $pattern = qr/word/;

my %res;
find( sub {
        return if not -T;  # ASCII or UTF-8 only

        open my $fh, '<', $_ or do {
            warn "Error opening $File::Find::name: $!";
            return;
        };

        while (<$fh>) { 
            if (/$pattern/) { 
                chomp;
                push @{$res{$File::Find::name}}, $_
            }
        }
    }, @dirs
);

for my $k (keys %res) { 
    say "In file $k:";
    say "\t$_" for @{$res{$k}};
}
```